# How to save bool value using shared preferences

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

So I created a categories section in my app where you can select multiple categories by clicking on the container. The container you select changes colour. What I want to do is save the choices selected using shared preferences and display it again whenever user wants to see his selected categories.

```
return GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    setState(() {
      if (isSelected == false) {
        isSelected = !isSelected;
        color = widget.color;
        print('Coming here');
      } else {
        isSelected = false;
        color = Colors.white;
      }
      prefs.setBool(_key, isSelected);
    });
  },
  child: AnimatedContainer(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(widget.padding),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: color,
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
    ),
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    child: Container(
      child: Text(
        widget.labelText,
        style: TextStyle(
            color: kLightBlue,
            fontFamily: 'clanproBold',
            fontSize: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 3),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

This is the code to create multiple containers.
How can I save the options?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, thank you for your question! Is there any chance that you might be able to update your code sample to show your entire widget, so that we can better help you?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you have to add the dependency of `shared preferences` at your `pubspec.yaml` file as follows:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  shared_preferences: "<newest version>"
```

After that you have to import to your class the package:

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
```

Then at the state, you want to save the options add the following code:

```
_saveOptions() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await prefs.setBool('option', true);
}
```

You can read the data you saved at SharedPreferences using the following code:

```
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  bool boolValue = prefs.getBool('option');
```

**Important:** You can only save **int**, **String**, **double** or **bool** variables using SharedPreferences.

So if you want to save the options the user gives, you can use only the types above.
You can make it work by passing the values of the options as **String** or **int** to SharedPrefrences and convert them back again.

Example:

```
Color color = new Color(0x#BD452C);
int colorValue = color.value;
String colorString = color.toString();
Color newColor = new Color(colorValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check this example I have created an example that will tell you how to save the shared preferences value and then retrieve it

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Users'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool isSelected = false;
  String stringValue = "No value";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAllSavedData();
    // You can use the initState where you can get all the saved categories and the assign it based on it.

    
  }

  getAllSavedData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    bool value = prefs.getBool("youKey");

    // For first time you get null data so no value 
    // is assigned so it will not assign anything
    if (value != null) stringValue = value.toString();

    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () async {
                if (isSelected == false) {
                  isSelected = !isSelected;
                  //color = Colors.pink;
                  print('Coming here');
                } else {
                  isSelected = false;
                  // color = Colors.white;
                }

                SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                prefs.setBool("youKey", isSelected);

                // This is where you save the data and then when the user second time opens  he will get the stoared data
                setState(() {});
              },
              child: AnimatedContainer(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                child: Container(
                  child: Text(
                    'S',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        fontFamily: 'clanproBold',
                        fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            // This is when you open the screen for second time you get the value as true
            Text('This is the value you saved $stringValue'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: I tried. It isn't working. setBool is only saving value as true, even if nothing is selected.

Comment: Use value instead of directly using true

_saveOptions(bool value) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await prefs.setBool('option', value);
}